How to disable authorization check for inner calls (backend to backend)
I have service A which configured using spring security, config:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true
)
@SecurityScheme(
        name = "bearerAuth",
        type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP,
        bearerFormat = "JWT",
        scheme = "bearer"
)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtTokenFilter jwtTokenFilter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer ->
                        httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(req -> req
                        .requestMatchers(
                                "/login/**",
                        ).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

Service A receives requests form front-end, and send request to another backend service B using FeignClient:
@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private SlApiClient slApiClient;

    public CustomerDTO getCustomerById(UUID id) {
        return slApiClient.getCustomerById(id;
    }

    /**
     * Another methods using slApiClient
     */
}

Feign client:
@FeignClient(url = "${endpoints.sl-api-uri}", name = "SL-API-CLIENT-V1", primary = false)
public interface SlApiClient {
    @GetMapping("/users/{id}}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('users.read')")
    CustomerDTO getCustomerById(@PathVariable UUID id);

    /**
     * Another methods
     */
}

So my question is how to awoid PreAuthorize security check for this inner call from service A to service B via FeignClient

Are you handing out jwts to browsers? Because this is not recommended according to the oauth2 specification and companies like okta and redis etc.

service A receives request from browser (with token), then making request to service B, service B don't have security, just @PreAuthorize annotation

if you already know the ip address of your first backend, then you can write a custom filter that extends OncePerRequestFilter and check the ip address and bypass the authorization.
maybe you could find a cleaner solution, but i would try this approach, if i don't find any other solution.
